# How can i identify session timeout in AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, timeout, afnetworking-2

i am creating an object of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager

```
    NSString *BaseURLString = @"http://192.168.1.202:81//CredentialsModule/CredentialService.asmx/details";
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager  manager];
   [manager POST:BaseURLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
    NSString *products = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"d"];
    NSLog(@"pro %@",products);

    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",products];
    NSData* data = [newString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError* error;
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"user id %@",jsonObjects);


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:CategoryViewController animated:YES];

   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

     NSLog(@"\n Error2: %ld",(long)operation.response.statusCode);
     NSLog(@"\n Error2: %@",  operation.responseString);

}];
```

suppose i am calling above web service and my session is timeout.So,i want to know is there any chance to identify session timeout before calling the service in afnetworking 2.0.
Please don't try to run  web service it won't work because its on local server !!

Comment: Logically, timeout is detected after N seconds of no response. It is better to check `NSError` `code` and `domain` properties to identify a timeout. The `code` should be `kCFURLErrorTimedOut ` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes,i have check NSError it return this Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x1095abbd0

Comment: {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1097178b0> { URL: http://192.168.1.202:81/PatientModule/PatientService.asmx/GetAllLisPatientCaseDetail } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 961;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 18 Feb 2014 13:18:22 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    jsonerror = true;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500),

Comment: NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.202:81/PatientModule/PatientService.asmx/GetAllLisPatientCaseDetail}

Comment: this is the whole error which i have got from NSError.
If you can find anything in that error,please share with me..thanks

Comment: It's not a timeout error. This error means, that your server script has crashed. Please, add details to your answer description in future. If you want to simulate timeout refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100841/artificially-create-a-connection-timeout-error