# how can I make an endpoint on express that never responds

Tags: node.js, express

I want write a test in mocha for how a timeout is handled.

I can set up a server that will never answer using netcat `nc -kl 8080` (thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/37465639/5203563).

However, since I already run an express server for all my other test endpoints inside mocha, it would be great if I could achieve the same thing with an express endpoint.

Does anybody know if that is possible?

Comment: This will lead to timeout in client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return the response from the route.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {});
```

Comment: This will lead to timeout in client side.

Comment: thanks. works perfect. should have probably tried that!

Answer (score 3):

Just don't return a response

```
 var app = require('express')();

 app.get('/fail', function(req, res) {
   // does nothing
 });

 app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: This will lead to timeout in client side.